# How to set up a rolling window in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to split the data into windows of equal chunks in the code below

```
a=c(1:50)
v=0
{for (i in seq(1,length(a),by=10)){
  v[i]=c(a[i:i+10])
  print(i)
}
```

I would like to see an output, 
v[1]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 
v[2]=[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I would call this *splitting* rather than *rolling* since there is no overlap among the components output.

Regarding the answers below the first produces a matrix with its columns  holding the components.  If that matrix is `m` then `m[, 1]` is the vector `1:10`.  This should only be used if the length of `a` is a multiple of 10.

The second answer produces a list whose components are the desired vectors.  If that list is `L` then `L[[1]]` is the vector `1:10`.

The third answer produces a matrix with its rows holding the components.  If that matrix is `mm` then `mm[1, ]` is the vector `1:10`.  This alternative should only be used if the length of `a` is a multiple of 10.

The fourth is the same as the third but it also works in the case that the length of `a` is not a multiple of 10.

```
# 1
matrix(a, 10)

# 2
n <- length(a)
split(a, rep(1:n, each = 10, length = n))

# 3
library(zoo)
rollapply(a, 10, by = 10, c)

# 4
library(zoo)
rollapply(1:45, 10, by = 10, `length<-`, value = 10, partial = TRUE, align = "left")
```

Comment: Here v[1] is equal to 1. The output I am aiming for is v[1]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].

Comment: If x, y and z are the three answers then v[1] is x[, 1], y[[1]] and z[1, ]. (updated)

Comment: If you put them in a list you must use [[...]], not [...].  If you want to use [...] then you can if you use a matrix.  What you are asking for is not how R works unless you want to create custom S3 or S4 objects which seems way beyond what is appropriate here.

Comment: Oh I see. I am a little new to R :) Let's see if someone else has a better solution though. Although v[1] doesn't have to be a list, it can be a column too.

Comment: Also note that you actually can write y[1] but then you will get a one component list which contains the vector of interest rather than the vector itself and I assume you don't want that.